# How to integrate SQL Server 2005 Express Edition to Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I use Visual Web Developer Express Edition 2008 and SQL Server 2008 Express edition. I have finished a project recently. But many of hosting firms don't have SQL Server 2008. So i decided to uninstall SQL Server 2008 and install SQL Server 2005. Then I would reproduce my database. I uninstalled SQL Server 2008, installed SQL Server 2005. In project, When i clicked "App_Data - Add new item - SQL Server Database", an error accured "**Connections to SQL server files (*.mdf) require SQL Server 2005 to function properly. Please verify the installation of the component or download from the URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkId=49251**". I couldn't add a new database to my project.

So how do i integrate SQL Server 2005 Express Edition to Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the setting under Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections for the SQL Server Instance Name refers to the name of your SQL Express 2005 instance.
Check SQL Server Express is running using the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: I don't know how i thank you my friend. It worked. It is so easy but if you don't know the answer, it looks like a mountain :) Thanks again.