# SQL Server 2008 & Visual Web Developer 2008 express editions: Connection to DB Fail!

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

So I saw this  question/comment...

[How to integrate SQL Server 2005 Express Edition to Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625991/how-to-integrate-sql-server-2005-express-edition-to-visual-web-developer-2008-exp/1626114#1626114)

And this is EXACTLY what I am having trouble with, only using SQL Server 2008 express edition and Visual Web Dev 2008 express. Everytime I try to click to add a new database I get the exact same error code.

I tried the response on the other question, and this did not solve the problem for me.

PLEASE HEEEEEELLLPP!!! Thanks

EDIT:

I should note that these are installed on my home laptop for learning purposes.

The instance must have been a named instance, though I am not sure of what that is. When I load it up, and select the connect: the "server name" appear as 'JUSTIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS' though I am not sure this is what is referred to as the instance name.

I did try this though in the visual studio data connection field, and it did not work, so I am assuming this is not right. So I am reading help on it but really lost...although it looks like it probably assigned a named instance for me, though I do not know what that was.

Thanks for helping the rookies learn!!

Comment: What is the instance name in the configuration manager and what is configured in the Data Connections settings?  Also, does the CM tool show that the server is running?

Comment: Step 1: Load up Sql Server Management Studio. Can you Log in and connect to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adding a database to the App_Data folder (rather than creating the database in SQL Management Studio), you are probably getting a conflict between the version of SQL you have installed and the one that Visual Studio expects. This is my current situation at work where I have Visual Studio 2008 Team and SQL Server 2008 - because I do not develop using App_Data, it doesn't really bother me.

Couple of things to try:

- Check if there are any service packs for your express edition
- Try uninstalling everything, then install sql server, then install visual studio
- Uninstall everything, let the express install sql server express for you
- Create the database in management studio and using the server explorer, create your tables and whatever else in visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting just `SQLEXPRESS` in the VS database settings?  I'm not sure if it works properly with the host name in front.  Mine at home just says `SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Yeah I put SQLEXPRESS in the Data Connection field, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Do you have SQl Server Express 2008 and Visual Web Developer 2008 express?